# Вставить имя файла из formdata

Tags: php, ajax

Создаю пдф на сервере. Хочу присвоить ей случайное имя. Но никак не пойму, как в php подхватить переменную

Создаем pdf - все работает

```
function createPDF() {  
        getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {  
            var  
             img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),  
             doc = new jsPDF({  
                 unit: 'px',  
                 format: 'a4'  
             });  
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);  
             var blob = doc.output('blob');

            var formData = new FormData();
            var dt = new Date();
            var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1 + "" + dt.getHours() + "" + dt.getMinutes();
            document.getElementById('fileName').value = time;
         
           formData.append('pdf', blob);
           formData.append('fileName', time);
            $.ajax(
            '/drova/upload.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){console.log(data)},
                error: function(data){console.log(data)}
            });
            form.width(cache_width);  
        });  
    }
```

Далее простейший обработчик, в котором я хочу получить filename и назвать так файл.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['filename'];
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/drova/".$name.".pdf"
);
?>
```

Файл создается, но без имени. Как мне создать файл с нужным мне именем, которое передается через   formData.append('fileName', $("#fileName").val());

var_dump POST показывает это - мне как раз эту цифру и нужно в название файла вставить

```
array(1) {
  ["fileName"]=>
  string(7) "5501226"
}
```

Comment: `formData.append('fileName', $("#fileName").val());` > `$name = $_POST['fileName'];`

Comment: у вас есть ключ с именем `pdf` и есть ключ с именем `fileName`. А вы почему-то в одном ищите второй....... а самое простое было бы вам просто посмотреть что находится в переменной `$_FILES` и сделать выводы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯     и аналогично с `$_POST`

Comment: Поправил php - но все равно файл с пустым именем.

Comment: Как именно поправил?  Уверен, что правильно поправил?

Comment: ключ в js один в php другой :рукалицо:

Comment: Я не уверен, что правильно поправил :) Если бы я был уверен - не задавал бы вопросов тут :) ПХП не мой язык, я использую эту функцию потому, что на perl такое сложно реализовать. Часть с ajax правильная, но что-то не так в пхп, и я не пойму, что именно. Я пробую разные варианты  $name =  $_FILES['fileName'];  $name =  $_FILES['time'];  $name =  $_POST['fileName'];  и другие. Но все равно пустота. Как мне понять, что filename вообще передается?

Comment: Ещё раз.... не надо играть в угадайку..... Берёте и смотрите что находится в `$_POST` и что в `$_FILES` и делаете выводы.

Comment: _Как мне понять, что filename вообще передается?_ - открываете в браузере network и смотрите какой запрос летит, var_dump($_POST, $_FILES); покажет что прилетает.  Возможно так ещё `$name = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)['fileName'];`. А по сути, имя можно не передавать а формировать его на php

Comment: Я проверил. В POST есть array с filename с нужным значением. Я пытаюсь его получить в обработчике $name = $_POST['filename'];   и далее всунуть в имя файла "/drova/".$name.".pdf"   но название все равно пустое.

Comment: В вопрос добавьте что var_dump показывает

Comment: Добавил в конец вопроса var_dump

Comment: ну вот, самый первый комментарий все ещё актуален

Comment: omg... Теперь понял, в чем ошибка была... Чувствительность к регистру. fileName и filnename - оказывается, разные вещи. Спасибо всем большое!